# Regarding product topology, why is $(X\times Y)\times Z$ homeomorphic to $X\times(Y\times Z)$?

Tags: general-topology

I want to set up "identity" function as the homeomorphism.
How to express an element in $(X \times Y) \times Z$? 
Is it $((x,y),z)$? 
Furthermore, when it is mapped to $(x,(y,z))$, can the function be called identity function?

I am thinking that when $f(x,(y,z))$ belongs to $A \times (B \times C)$, how to show $f^{-1}(A \times (B \times C))=(A \times B) \times C$?

Thank you very much!

Comment: *[Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)* is some MathJax tutorial

Comment: Not sure the title is a meaningful question, since $(X \times Y) \times Z = (X \times Y) \times Z$.

Comment: @Ken they aren't equal by the usual construction.

Comment: @MattSamuel Looks like the title was changed so that the two quantities are different, so I'm good now. (They were equal originally.)

Comment: the map $((x,y), z) \mapsto (x,(y,z))$ could reasonably be called an *associator*.

Answer (score 4):

The map $f\colon (X\times Y)\times Z\to X\times(Y\times Z)$ defined by
$$
f\colon \bigl((x,y),z\bigr)\mapsto\bigl(x,(y,z)\bigr)
$$
is obviously bijective.

The fact that it is continuous is readily established: let $U$, $V$, $W$ be open sets in $X$, $Y$, $Z$ respectively.

Then
$$
f^{-1}\bigl(U\times(V\times W)\bigr)=(U\times V)\times W.
$$
Since also
$$
f\bigl((U\times V)\times W\bigr)=U\times(V\times W)
$$
we have that $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are continuous.

Comment: Is it because of the bijective property, we can write f((UxV)xW)=Ux(VxW)? I doubt that whether f it would be a circular argument if I have written it down.

Comment: @user219456 It's just a simple check.

Comment: @user219456 do you know what is circular argument?

Answer (score 1):

One way to prove this result is to use elementary category theory.
[Products](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_(category_theory)) can be defined in an abstract way and the associative law you wish holds in this general setting.

Coming back to topological spaces, you need to verify that the [product of a family of topological spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_topology) is indeed a product in the category of topological spaces, which amounts to verify the universal property defining the product (see again the two wikipedia links given above).

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track. Elements of $(X \times Y) \times Z$ can indeed be written uniquely as $((x,y),z)$, a pair, of which the first element is another pair.

To prove the homeomorphism, we note that your proposed mapping is certainly a bijection.

So continuity of it, and its inverse, are the only issues, really.

General fact about topological products: a function $f: T \rightarrow X \times Y$ from a space into a product is continuous iff $T: \pi_X \circ f : T \rightarrow X$ and $ T: \pi_Y \circ f : T \rightarrow Y$ are both continuous, where $\pi_X$ and $\pi_Y$ are the projections from the product onto $X$ resp. $Y$.

Let your map be called $F$, from $(X \times Y) \times Z \rightarrow X \times (Y \times Z)$, defined by $F( ((x,y),z) ) = (x, (y,z))$.

Then $F$ is continuous iff $\pi_X \circ F$ and $\pi_{Y \times Z} \circ F$ are continuous.

The former maps $((x,y),z)$ to $x$, and so is just the composition $\pi_X \circ \pi_{X \times Y}$, which is continuous as a composition of continuous projections, one from $(X \times Y) \times Z$ onto $X \times Y$, and then from $X \times Y$ onto $X$.

The map $\pi_{Y \times Z} \circ F$ is continuous (as a map into $Y \times Z$) iff both $\pi_Y \circ \pi_{Y \times Z} \circ F$ and $\pi_Z \circ \pi_{Y \times Z} \circ F$ are continuous, and these can be written again as direct projections or a compositions of projections again (do it!). Conclusion: $F$ is continuous.

Then do a similar song and dance for the inverse, using the universal property again.

Comment: Regarding the last part showing pi(YxZ)F to be continuous, I have to decompose it into pi(Y)pi(YxZ)F and pi(Z)pi(YxZ)F, then pi(YxZ) appears again, then would it be a circular argument?

Comment: No, $\pi_{Y \times Z}$ is continuous by the definition of the product topology on $X \times (Y \times Z)$ (it's the smallest topology that makes both projections continuous).

Comment: It's not circular, you reduce it to the continuity of another map into a smaller product, using the same characterisation of continuous maps into products.